# Is there a way to push data to silverlight client without polling and without sockets?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, push, duplex

Do you know is there a way to push data to SL 4.0 client without polling (even under the hood) and without sockets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think so. Those are the two methods one would use.

Answer (score 1):

SL4 added multicast support - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/11/18/udp-multicast-in-silverlight-4.aspx - so that can be an alternative if you're on an intranet and you don't need to push something to a specific client.

Comment: Does listening on a UDP port not constitute using sockets?

Comment: Under the hood all communication goes through sockets, so yes :) But for multicast you're not opening a server socket that anyone can send data to your application, you're subscribing to a specific "channel" which you'll be using to listen to shared data.